# Sending data from Arduino to Python using pyserial

Tags: python, arduino

My Arduino Uno board is connected to the COM12 port. I am using pyserial to send my sensor readings to Python so that I can send it to a PHP script. Python is not accessing the port and is showing the following error.

```
SerialException: could not open port 'COM12': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

[check this image to see the command and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3rNx.jpg)

I want to send the sensor values which Arduino reads to a PHP script. Can anyone help me fix this or suggest me any other way to get it done?

I have tried using an Ethernet shield but that's not working.

Comment: The serial port appears to already be opened by another program - perhaps a terminal program of some sort, perhaps another instance of your script that's still running.

Comment: I have opened only Arduino Serial Window and python window, hence there is no script which is running at this time.

Comment: Well, if you have the Arduino serial monitor open, then you're obviously not going to be able to open the same port in your script.

Comment: Thanks alot. It is working now. I am new to embedded coding so I thought I would need that serial window opened too.

Comment: Why did you take a screenshot? You can just copy paste that text.